Unable to start vsftpd.service on Centos9 Stream using Virtualbox
I'm unable to start the vsftpd.service. Here's the error I get when I try to start it
Job for vsftpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status vsftpd.service" and "journalctl -xeu vsftpd.service" for details.

This is the result of running journalctl -xeu vsftpd.service
Jun 04 18:30:30 centos2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Vsftpd ftp daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit vsftpd.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit vsftpd.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 9077 and the job result is failed.

This is what I get when I run  systemctl status vsftpd.service
× vsftpd.service - Vsftpd ftp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-06-04 18:33:30 EDT; 4min 22s ago
    Process: 49019 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 1ms

Jun 04 18:33:27 centos2 systemd[1]: Starting Vsftpd ftp daemon...
Jun 04 18:33:30 centos2 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 04 18:33:30 centos2 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 04 18:33:30 centos2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Vsftpd ftp daemon.

I have visited numerous forums and modified
/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
in several ways to no avail. Here is the current status of
/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
without the commented out lines
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=fdin
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES

pam_service_name=ftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES

Here is the result of doing  ss -tlpn | grep :21
LISTEN 0      32                 *:21              *:*    users:(("vsftpd",pid=47793,fd=3))


I don't see a listen_port directive so the default will be used which is port  21.  Is this port already in use? You can check it using ss -tlpn | grep ':21'  or lsof -ni :21. Also look at SELinux messages for any avc's  ausearch -i -m avc -ts recent.

Can you show what systemctl cat vsftpd says? And are line feeds in this file correct when you run sed -n l /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf  ?  Lines should end with $ character only
